# range attributes in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, attributes, cells

I am wondering if we can give attributes to cells automatically by using a script in google apps script.

Like for my case i have a code which does some mathematic calculation and returns a value with 5 decimals something like this : 10,76283.

What would be perfect is to add a code to it in order to return 10,7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. No need to do it in scripts. I simply had to put the whole colonne with a format in the format tab. And it does the work.